# How to load cookies from a text file in python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I've been trying to load raw cookies **(not json)** but using a txt file instead of declaring it directly inside a variable but getting no success , Here's my code ->

cookies.txt

```
{"PHPSESSID": "ibd1biktq4tfm3k4j790juf19d", "security": "impossible"}
```

my python script

```
file = open("cookies.txt", "r")
file = file.readlines()
str1 = " "
cookies = str1.join(file)     # for converting list into string
requests.get("http://localhost/dvwa", cookies=cookies)
```

output : `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Also if i do `print(cookies)` it outputs `{"PHPSESSID": "ibd1biktq4tfm3k4j790juf19d", "security": "impossible"}` and declaring the same output directly into the variable "cookies" works ...

Can anyone please clarify what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to parse the string to Python dictionary using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```py
from ast import literal_eval

with open("cookies.txt", "r") as f_in:
    cookies = literal_eval(f_in.read())

requests.get("http://localhost/dvwa", cookies=cookies)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , it worked with no issues